# Слишком быстрая прокрутка по тачпаду

Tags: linux, fedora

Пользуюсь Fedora 26 с гномом на Wayland, почему-то когда использую прокрутку двумя пальцами по тачпаду содержимое экрана листает слишком быстро. Можно как-то конфигурировать скорость прокрутки?
Настройка через xinput не дает никаких результатов.
P.S. Прокрутка колесом мыши работает адекватно

UPD:

xinput --list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xinput --list-props 6

```
Device 'xwayland-pointer:13':
    Device Enabled (117):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (119): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (242): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (243):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (244):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (245):    10.000000
```

xinput --list-props 7

```
Device 'xwayland-relative-pointer:13':
    Device Enabled (117):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (119): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (242): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (243):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (244):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (245):    10.000000
```

Comment: так приложите список свойств, которыми может манипулировать xinput: `$ xinput --list-props "<имя или идентификатор устройства>"`

Comment: а причем тут xinput?

Comment: @eri пока гуглил много было вариантов настроить этот параметр через него

Comment: а в иксах такое повторяется?

Comment: @НикитаГордеев Очень много не достающей информации. Вы где листаете? В Chrome, Firefox, Emacs, Vim, LyX, LibreOffice, PDF readers... Какое железо, какая модель (ноута думаю раз есть тач). Просто сам пользуюсь Fedora уже лет 6  за все это время нареканий минимально к ней. Из опыта работы с различными железом вообще, могу сказать, что стоит подумать о дефекте тачпада...

Comment: @Hellseher на винде скролится нормально. на федоре - везде заметно быстрее. если проскроллить по всей высоте тачпада то хром пролистает примерно 2 страницы(весь видимый контент на экране), LibreOffice столько же, в ff около 3-4, в терминале около 5-6 страниц. по горизонтали в таблице(LibreOffice, google docs) я даже не замечаю в какую сторону крутится. В той же системе, но с xorg(выбрал при авторизации) та же ситуация. Ноутбук msi gp60, по тачпаду удалось узнать только "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"

Comment: `dconf-editor`, попытаться найти там `touchpad` и поменять `motion-acceleration`

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n там нет такого(или похожего) параметра.

Answer (score 2):

За скорость прокрутки отвечает значение `VertScrollDelta`.
Чем оно больше - тем скорость прокрутки меньше.
Узнать текущее:

```
synclient -l | grep VertScrollDelta
```

Выставить новое (БЕЗ ПРОБЕЛОВ около знака `=`):

```
synclient VertScrollDelta=100
```

Чтобы не слетало после перезагрузки можно добавить в `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`

Более подробно [тут](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))

Comment: `$ sudo dnf install synclient
Последняя проверка окончания срока действия метаданных: 0:40:08 назад, Вт 26 сен 2017 19:09:06.
Нет пакета synclient.
Ошибка: Совпадений не найдено`

Comment: В F26 они его в xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-legacy-1.9.0-4.fc26.x86_64.rpm переименовали, а поумолчанию вместо него впилили свой  libinput - либо попробовать поиграться с libinput - либо снести libinput и поставить xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-legacy